# Puppet agent not following `server` setting

Tags: linux, puppet

I have a very strange issue with Puppet 2.7.18 (on a Raspberry Pi) that started all of the sudden. In simple terms, the agent only partially follows the 'server' directive in `puppet.conf`.

The following works:

```
$ sudo puppet agent -t --server my.puppet.server
```

but, if i instead set it in `puppet.conf`, it doesn't seem to follow it.

```
$ grep server /etc/puppet/puppet.conf
server=my.puppet.server
```

I even confirmed it with the genconfig variable, which appears to agree with the fact that it is properly configured:

```
$ sudo puppet agent --configprint server
my.puppet.server
```

The strange part is that when I'm running it without the explicit server argument, I get the following error repeated:

```
$ sudo puppet agent -t
[...]
err: /Stage[main]/MyModule::Puppet/File[some_file.sh]: Could not evaluate: getaddrinfo: Name or service not known Could not retrieve file metadata for puppet:///modules/MyModule/some_file.sh: getaddrinfo: Name or service not known at /etc/puppet/modules/MyModule/manifests/another_file.pp:31
[...]
err: Could not send report: getaddrinfo: Name or service not known
```

Can anyone offer any kind of insight or explanation to why such behavior would happen?

Comment: Do you have an actual problem connecting to the server? Or are you mainly concerned with the error that is printed?

Comment: @JoelESalas Well, the run fails, since it is unable to retrieve files. Hence it ends with a long list of `[...] has failures: true`.

Comment: Can you post the entire output of the Puppet run?

Comment: @JoelESalas please see the updated example above.

Comment: Maybe run `tcpdump port 53` to see what address it is actually trying to use?  Your error messages are a bit odd, since it sure seems like you were able to retrieve the catalog from the server, or did you also get a message that a cached catalog was being used.  Is your system running a really restrictive firewall, or are you using selinux or something?

Comment: You know what, I think it was a very odd DNS issue. Puppet is running across the internat, CloudFlare is being used for the DNS (to accelerate/protect other web properties on the domain). 

In any case, I can no longer reproduce the issue. I'll just go ahead and close this out as a temporary hiccup.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely caused by a temporary DNS issue.